# Executing a controller action when a button is clicked on the client

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Are we supposed to be able to follow a AJAX call in the debugger to see what's going on? Because for some reason it seems like the call isn't going to where it's supposed to go to.

When stepping through the program, after the `url: '@URL.Action("DidItWork", "Home")` call, it goes to:

```
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

Followed by several other methods; however, it doesn't appear that it hits any of the lines of code in the DidItWork() action method (based on breakpoints).

I then get `Error: Not Found. Status: error. Console: [object Object]`

Thoughts/suggestions on how to resolve this issue of the @Url.Action call not setting off any break points in the DidItWork() action method? Because the @Url.Action call isn't getting to the desire effect of having reaching SendEmailAsync().

**The following code is in _Layout.cshtml**

```
@*script for someone who presses the send/email button*@ 
<script>
    $("#sendButton").click(function () {
        alert("Send button pressed");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DitItWork", "Home")',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success. It worked: " + result);
            }, 
            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
                console.log("Hello");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.dir(xhr);
                console.log("Good-bye");
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**The following code is in HomeController.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork()
{
        var dash = "dash equals nash";

        var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test2 username2", Email = "testemail2@gmail.com" };
        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "passwordGoesHere1!");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account");

            return View();
        }

        //AddErrors(result);
        return View();    
}
```

Comment: Your action Name in ajax url is wrong!!!!!!!

Comment: Appreciate your help -- always nice to have an extra set of eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Action name is Di**d**ItWork, but you are sending request to Di**t**ItWork. But for the feature install some tool or use already existing in you web browser to check where request is sending(for example I am using firebug in firefox).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the action name that you are calling from ajax. It is different from your action name in your controller. Also check if the jquery is loaded before calling ajax. I hope it will help.

Also check if any filters are used in

```
public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
```